# Angular dynamcly setting the user's language

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a service that fetches the Userinfo which contains his or hers preferred language and I want to use it in my controller to change the language of my application when the user loggs in,

however when I do '$scope.User.locale' which should return the preferred language I keep getting undefined.

My code is:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var controllers = angular.module('portal.controllers');

controllers.controller('mainController', function mainController($scope ,UserService, NavigationService, $translate, localStorageService) {
    localStorageService.clearAll();
    $scope.User = UserService.getUserinfo();

    $scope.setLang = function (langKey) {
        $translate.uses(langKey);
        $.removeCookie(Constants.cookie_locale);
        var domain = document.domain;

        $.cookie(Constants.cookie_locale, langKey, {path: "/", domain: domain});
    };

    $scope.logout = function(){
        NavigationService.logout();
    };

    console.log($scope.User);

    console.log($scope.User.locale);
    $translate.uses($scope.User.locale);

    });
}());
```

UserService:

```
(function(){
'use strict';

var userServices = angular.module('portal.services');

userServices.factory('UserService', ['UserInfo','localStorageService', function(UserInfo, localStorageService){
    return new UserService(UserInfo, localStorageService);
}]);

function UserService(UserInfo, localStorageService){
    this.UserInfo = UserInfo;
    this.localStorageService = localStorageService;
}

UserService.prototype.getUserinfo = function(){
    var userinfo = this.localStorageService.get(Constants.key_userinfo);
    if(userinfo !== null){
        return userinfo;
    } else {
        return this.UserInfo.query($.proxy(function(data){
            this.localStorageService.add(Constants.key_userinfo, JSON.stringify(data));
        }, this));
    }
};

UserService.prototype.clearUserInfo = function(){
    this.localStorageService.remove(Constants.key_userinfo);
};

}());
```

Userinfo:

```
(function(){
'use strict';
var data = angular.module('portal.data');

data.factory('UserInfo', function($resource){
   return $resource('/users-rs/api/userinfo',{}, {
        query: {method: 'GET'}, isArray: false}
   );
});
}());
```

$scope.User does bind the correct features to the elements I want so I know it's somewhere in there :p, Also when the page is loaded and the setLang function is called it does it's magic, now I only need to get it working on initial loading of the app.

Thx for checking into it 
J.

Comment: Can you post the implementation of UserService.getUserinfo();?

Comment: I assume getUserinfo is getting the info from a web service or something. It's probably returning a $resource or a promise. In either case, the result doesn't have what you need. for a promise, you need to then() it. For a resource, you'll need to $then() it.

Comment: Indeed UserService is returning a $resource, can you give me an example of how to do $then